# Calling method on Document interface in Java

Tags: java, xml, interface, document

I am trying to parse an XML file in Java and after getting the `DocumentBuilder` object, I call the parse method on it to get a `Document` object.
e.g. `Document dom = docbuild.parse(fileName);`

Then to get the root of the XML file, I use the method `dom.getDocumentElement();`.
Since `Document` is an interface as defined in the javadocs, how are we able to call a method on it without defining it first?

My main objective is to create a class that inherits the Document interface, so I have to implement it. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DocumentBuilder` returns some implementation of `Document`. You don't have to worry about implementing the `Document` interface, somebody has already done that for you. The returned document will represent the XML document, which is what you want.

Comment: But what I want to achieve is something like myDocument extends Document, so that my myDocument object can get the root node of the XML file using getDocumentElement().

How do you think I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The use of the document is as follow:

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = builder.parse("StringOfTheSource");
```

These tree steps will fix your problem.