# Working with interfaces in Java. E.g. DOM Document Interface

Tags: java, xml, dom, interface, extends

First, my question in relative to the one: [Calling method on Document interface in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476021/calling-method-on-document-interface-in-java)

But I want to ask more.

E.g., as far I understood, "someone" has written a class which implements the Document interface and by using the DocumentBuilder.parse method something is returned. So, question 1: What is returned? A reference to a class/object? A reference to a class'/object's interface? How is this done? And since the returned type is of "Document" interface, how can one call methods of it?

Also, (question 2) since the DocumentBuilder is returning an interface, how can one extend the class of which an object is returned from DocumentBuilder.parse method in order to implement an extension of the Document interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type (class) that is returned by the parse method:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory f = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = f.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(...);
System.out.println(doc.getClass().getName());
```

and if you use use nothing but the JDK you will most likely see:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl
```

This class implements the `Document` interface, so you can call all methods of that interface on that instance.

As for the second question, you would have to create your own `DocumentBuilderFactory` along with implementations of all the other required interfaces and classes. You *might* be able to reuse and extend existing groups of implementation classes, but that really depends on the design of those classes.